# What size is Savage Worlds Kerberos Club?

Tags: savage-worlds

Is the Savage Worlds edition of The Kerberos Club sized the same as the Explorer Edition and Superpowers Companion, or is it a more traditional 8.5"x11" sized book?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0857440586) says:

> Product Dimensions: 10.9 x 8.5 x 1 inches

Comment: RPGGeek.com is another excellent resource for questions like this. It agrees: [294 Letter-size pages and 2 lbs](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/86766/the-kerberos-club-savage-worlds).

Comment: Just to confirm, I saw it my physically at FLGS yesterday and it is indeed a full sized book- not a little one like the Explorer Edition.